# Proper time stretch in After Effects for multiple layers

Tags: after-effects

So when I stretch the two chosen layers, they do stretch together, but the collision point shifts so I need to correct it manually.

How can I simultaneously change the length of the layers without messing the scene?

I've tried to show the things in this picture. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It works the way it is supposed to. You just need to realign the layers afterwards.

Comment: Well, I know. I'm just hoping there is another way to adjust the length of the composition.

Comment: I'm having a play and a look at documentation to see if there is another way...

Comment: Seems like a job for a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest this two clips in new composition, and change time starching on it.

Comment: I know, but it's not smart since there are some After Effects transitions.
I mean, if I stretch the layers, the transition just goes slower.
But in your case it will be just drop in framerate.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it works, but you may add a marker on each layer when the transition without stretching starts pressing this key: *

Then, I think the markers should be paired with the original frames and then you just have to match them in the timeline again.

Sorry if this doesn't work or there's a better way, it's just an idea.